# How do I retrieve a list of month names where there are records within a current year in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do you retrieve a list of Months where there are records for a specific client by a specific year?

My table table name is called Date that has entries as DATE: 2019-11-21.

I've tried grouping by Month by I think I need to use something with AS to get the month name?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Requests WHERE Client_id = ? GROUP BY MONTH";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();   
$data = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();

if(mysqli_num_rows($data) === 0){
    echo "<br>no results";
}else{
    echo "<br>Results<br>";
}

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
?>
     /* Desired Output:
         Each Month Name
     */
<?php
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the DB schema?

Comment: you just want the month names where there are records for given client and given year?

Comment: Also you are not using prepared statements correctly. You need to parameterize an bind the variables.

Comment: yes thats all Just the month names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`month`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) is a function in mysql. So unless you have a column named `month` (not a good idea), then you need to use it properly. If your date column is named `date`, then you would pass that to the month function.

```
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(`date`), * 
        FROM Requests 
        WHERE Client_id = ? 
        GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)";
```

If you want to restrict it to a specific year, add that to the where request:

```
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(`date`), * 
        FROM Requests 
        WHERE Client_id = ? 
        AND YEAR(`date`) = '2019' 
        GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)";
```

(as placeholder)

```
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(`date`), * 
        FROM Requests 
        WHERE Client_id = ? 
        AND YEAR(`date`) = ? 
        GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $year);
```

Note that this will actually group the results together (one row per month), not order them, so you may not be getting what you want.

Comment: Hope you dont mind the edit, Its easier to understand if the query is visible

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's fine, I was thinking it should be formatted better.

Comment: Suggest making the year value a placeholder as well.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Good idea, I just threw it in like this because it's a static value, and to demonstrate the value that would go in there.